# Hibernate session vs Thread safety

Tags: java, hibernate, session, orm, synchronization

How to attain thread safety while using hibernate session. While performing CRUD operations on database using session in a multi threaded environment i frequently encounter database and session are out of sync exceptions.Mine is a multi-threaded application that tries to lock an object(make an entry into lock table) while it is in use by another user for a particular span of time and then release the lock(remove entry from lock table). Can i make the CRUD methods synchronized ? If i could make what impact could it make while the application being executed on a multi threaded environment.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to create session per request and close it. Not quite sure how you setup your configuration, but if you look at hibernate developer guide or docs it will guide you.

Example:

```
Session sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
sess.beginTransaction();
```

//your DB actions will be performed here.

```
sess.update(profile);

sess.getTransaction().commit();
sess.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do want to add that I would encourage you to use a different locking strategy.

Row-level locks do not scale well when high concurrency is needed.  Most database platforms will eventually escalate row-level locks to page or worse table-level locks if too many row-level locks are requested.  This will have a massive impact on performance, concurrency, and scalability.

I would instead suggest you look into optimistic locking instead.

Optimistic locking avoids pushing locks to the database but instead allows the persistence provider to maintain this state.  This is done by providing a `@Version` annotated field that holds a seeded value that uniquely identifies the versioned state of a row.

This approach scales well because the shared resource (the database) no longer blocks concurrent operations against the same row.  It also allows practically limitless operations against the table without lock concurrency contention.  Instead, locking is delegated to the persistence provider who maintains this `@Version` annotated field and can determine if the row has been changed since the last time the persistence provider queried the row.

In short, the first person to update a row using Optimistic Locking wins, all subsequent updates based on the version state prior to the first update will fail with an `OptimisticLockException`.  It is then up to your code on how you would like to retry the operation or elect to ask the user to start over.